# Blender To Substance - Large Texture = Low Quality Problem

Tags: texturing, uv

So I have been having problems with texturing in Substance painter Due to the Texture being way to large. I use blender and before exporting I UV Unwrap Large meshes by "Smart UV Unwrapping". Later on In the UV editor I enlarge the Unwrap to get better pixel density by making the UV squares smaller making the textures alot smaller in substance painter but when I export and scale the textures in Substance painter I start to get seams for no reasons. I dont know how to make my textures look high quality and realistic without it getting large in texturing programs. Their must be a simple solution for this that I can't see. Any help would be great!

Images:
[image: enter image descriptienter image description hereon here]

[image]

LINK TO FILE: https://mega.nz/file/Amw2jSpa#iSp-IuTzMf_5KX7UaomA67MgAFyTGpIBvi_0WKQMVNI

Comment: Share your blend file, so someone can take a look at your object or UV's

Comment: I added in the Link.